# Variable not incrementing in jQuery / JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, infinite-scroll

For some reason my variable keeps resetting to 2 despite me wanting to increment the variable when a function is called. It's really annoying me and I've refactored the code several times to no avail! It should be simple...

Here is my code:

```
( function( $ ) {
        $( document ).ready( function () {
            var count = 2;
            var total = <?php echo $loop->max_num_pages; ?>;
            if ( count <= total ) {
                $( window ).scroll( function() {
                    if ( $( window ).scrollTop() == $( document ).height() - $( window ).height() ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                            type:'POST',
                            data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no=" + count + '&loop_file=forums', 
                            success: function( html ){
                                $( "#content" ).append( html );
                            }
                        });
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );
```

EDIT: Thanks for your responses so far! Updated code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageCount = 2;
    total = <?php echo $loop->max_num_pages; ?>;
    jQuery( window ).scroll( function() {
        if  ( jQuery( window ).scrollTop() == jQuery( document ).height() - jQuery( window ).height() ){
            console.log( 'Old value: ' + pageCount );
            if ( pageCount > total ){
                return false;
            } else {
                loadArticle( pageCount );
            }
            pageCount++;
            console.log( 'New value: ' + pageCount );
        }
    }); 

    function loadArticle( pageNumber ) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            type:'POST',
            data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no=" + pageNumber + '&loop_file=forums', 
            success: function( html ){
                jQuery( "#content" ).append( html );
            }
        });
    return false;
    }
</script>
```

New value is always 3 and old value is always 2 (output in console) so it's still being reset...

**SOLVED:** The html callback in the ajax method was causing the issue. Moving the increment into there worked! New code:

```
( function( $ ) {
        pageCount = 2;
        total = <?php echo $loop->max_num_pages; ?>;
        $( window ).scroll( function() {
            if  ( $( window ).scrollTop() == $( document ).height() - $( window ).height() ){
                if ( pageCount > total ){
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                        type:'POST',
                        data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no=" + pageCount + '&loop_file=forums', 
                        success: function( html ){
                            $( "#content" ).append( html );
                            pageCount++;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );
```

Comment: I think that your `html` that is returns back in response contain the same script that make your variable again 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

two things first:

var can be shortened as such:

```
var var1 = 'string',
    var2 = 'int';
```

Don't mix php inside JS - it's messy. Create a hidden span and assign data tags to it and call like that

secondarily, that's because the value gets reset whenever you call the function. Place outside, or pass a parameter called count so you can make it more generic and use it throughout your project.

Answer (score 2):

Define count variable outside the function.

e.g.

```
var count = 2;
( function( $ ) {
        $( document ).ready( function () {
            var total = <?php echo $loop->max_num_pages; ?>;
            if ( count <= total ) {
                $( window ).scroll( function() {
                    if ( $( window ).scrollTop() == $( document ).height() - $( window ).height() ) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php bloginfo( 'wpurl' ) ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                            type:'POST',
                            data: "action=infinite_scroll&page_no=" + count + '&loop_file=forums', 
                            success: function( html ){
                                $( "#content" ).append( html );
                            }
                        });
                        count++;
                    }
                });
            } else {
                return;
            }
        });
    })( jQuery );
```

Comment: You should never use global variables

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question, still having issues!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the var `count` is local to your method. This means that it is only alive in that method call. Next time you call your function again, it will create a different `count` with the value 2 since that is the value you specify on your declaration. Move the variable declaration outside the method and everything should be fine.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I've updated with new code but I'm still having the issue. The variable is now outside the method, but the variable still isn't updating properly.